# Measurement of current and measurement of momentum of the electrons

Tags: quantum-measurements

Is a measurement of the current flowing through some material a measurement of the momentum of the electrons? Does their wavefunction collapse to an (approximate?) wavefunction of momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is measure of average momentum(or velocity $v_d$) gained by the electron due to applied Electric field in a very short period of time($\tau$) between the collision with other electrons or ions in the lattice.

Since at room temperature the electrons are very frequently undergoing collisions, the electrons can described only as statistical ensemble due to decoherence.

Yes the electrons occupy momentum eigen states with some probabilities which are given by the distribution function which depends on temperature.

Comment: So, let me see if I got that right: the single electron is in a momentum eigenstate, that precise momentum eigenstate can only be known statistically, meaning there are a fraction of electrons that are in one precise momentum eigenstate and a fraction of electrons that are in different momentum eigenstate depending on the Boltzmann weights. Is that correct?

Comment: @Masterme Yes, your inference is correct.